# Match outer divs width to the max width of inner div with CSS and flex layout

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I limit an outer element to shrink to the size of the inner one with css?

I have created a fiddle to reflect the problem I am  experiencing a bit better:

https://jsfiddle.net/Holger50/4tx7smeb/

```
.holder {
  display: flex;
  }

.left {
  flex: 3;
  max-width: 500px;
  /*display:inline-block;*/
  }

.right {
  flex: 1;
  }

.someInnerContentWithWidth {
  width: 400px;
  }

<div class='holder'>
  <div class='left'>
    <div class='someInnerContentWithWidth'>
      Content with fixed width
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    This should take up the rest of the space
  </div>
 </div>
```

The right div should have all remaining space that is not used by the blue area (that has a fixed width)

The first box works as expected, it takes over the maximum amount of space and after it reaches max-width, the right div takes the rest. Fine so far but how can I have the outer left div to max-width the inner blue content area? The blue area cannot extent any further and needs to stay with that width.

The use of "display:inline-block;" is not working properly as the flex layout predicts the outer width.
Likely there is some easy solution to it.

Comment: flex-shrink:0 to the one that you that you need to stay fixed

Comment: flex-shrink:0 does not work. The thing is that both divs may become smaller (also the inner content) but it must not extend any further if the inner div reached the max-width.

Comment: remove flex:3 ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Holger50/4tx7smeb/57/

If I remove flex:3 and ann flex-shrink:0 instead, the left side shrinks correctly to the height of the inner content. But what it will not do then is resize in a ratio of 2:1. Means, it will resize the inner div to the minimum width that it is capable of and does not resize at all on the left side. What I want to achieve is that left size also expands normally up to the maximum that the inner div is capable of